# How to use EmguCV (OpenCV in C#)?

Tags: c#, opencv

I don't understand what I have to install to make EmguCV work.I opened the sample-src provided with EmguCV ,but I get errors in Visual studio 2008.

I also tried other .NET wrappers for OpenCV,but none of them worked(including the examples). A message "(sample program) has encounted a problem and needs to close.Please report this error to microsoft bla bla bla" is shown after I run any program that uses the OpenCV.

How to make this work in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are all the required .dlls in place? Try copying all the Emgu .dlls to the directory containing the .exe.

To automate this I added a post-build event in Visual Studio:

```
xcopy /Y /D /F $(ProjectDir)Emgu.CV.Binary-2.0.1.0\*.dll $(TargetDir)
```

You need to set the correct source directory (I like to keep my libs along with the sources).

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with examples when I used Visual Studio 2010, and this is what I did:

1. Removed References: Emgu.CV.dll   Emgu.UI.dll  Emgu.Util.dll
2. From 'Project' menu -> Preferences -> and changed the .Net Framework target to 3.5
3. I added the DLLs that I have downloaded (the ones with the same name I deleted before)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice writeup on this added after the answers above: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257502/Creating-Your-First-EMGU-Image-Processing-Project