# How to install and use Emgu CV in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, emgucv

I'm trying to do an image processing project using Emgu CV, but I still dont know about the requirements. Can anybody tell me what the required dll files are? And where should I copy them in order to use that wrapper? Please describe from the start. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

There is a complete installation guide on the project wiki:  http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation . There is also [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869732/how-to-use-emgucv-opencv-in-c) on SO. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have written a full installation guide here that should help all visual studio newcomers to EMGU hope this helps any who visit.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EMGU_Image_Processing.aspx

Comment: @Chris: You just copied it from wiki. Why the heck the wiki English is terrible? Loads of grammar mistake in every 7 words out of 10 and spelling mistakes. What makes you guys think its a product? I couldn't get it working, it always says either bad image format or couldn't load cvextern. I did all x64, environ variable, copying dlls to project, bing folder, setting build platform target etc etc etc all you can think but no dice. You guys are useless

Answer (score 2):

Just posting this so that it might help someone who comes up with the same isse of setting up EmguCv.

https://notebookbft.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/setting-up-emgu-cv-project-with-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

@Razzie is correct. I found it helpful include these DLLs in your OpenCV assembly project with a copy on build/change: cv110.dll, cvaux110.dll, cxcore110.dll, highgui110.dll, opencv_ffmpeg110.dll and ml110.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Installation is very simple , just read http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation , Download from sourceforge.net and install as you usually install other programs.